# Acumatica How to programmatically create Project Activity?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create an Activity after creation of a Project, I am getting the following errors

The item ProjectTaskID is not found (restricted:False,external:True,value:Management)
The item ContractID is not found (restricted:False,external:False,value:2285)

Code Location in RowUpdating after the project has already been created.

```
                   var projTask = (PMTask)PXSelect<PMTask,
                   Where<PMTask.taskCD, Equal<Required<PMTask.taskCD>>,
                And<PMTask.projectID, Equal<Required<PMTask.projectID>>>>>
                    .SelectSingleBound(Base, new object[] { }, "Management", Base.Project.Current.ContractID);
                int projTID = projTask.TaskID.Value;
                        CRActivityMaint ent1 = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CRActivityMaint>();
                        CRActivity fold1 = new CRActivity();
                        fold1 = ent1.Activities.Insert(fold1);
                        fold1.Subject = "Drawings";
                        fold1.Type = "FC";

                        fold1.ContactID = Base.Project.Current.ContractID;
                        ent1.Activities.Update(fold1);
                        PMTimeActivity t1 = new PMTimeActivity();
                        t1.ContractID = Base.Project.Current.ContractID;
                        t1.Summary = "Drawings";

                        t1.TrackTime = true;
                        t1.ProjectID = Base.Project.Current.ContractID;
                        t1.ProjectTaskID = projTID;


                        ent1.TimeActivitiesOld.Insert(t1);
                        ent1.TimeActivity.Current = t1;

                        ent1.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: What I would do is run a debug session from Visual Studio put a breakpoint on PressSave and when you hit it check if you have matching ProjectTaskID and ContractID in the database using a db management utility like SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because the TimeActivity was not initialized properly

```
                        CRActivityMaint ent1 = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CRActivityMaint>();
                        CRActivity fold1 = new CRActivity();
                        fold1 = ent1.Activities.Insert(fold1);
                        fold1.Subject = "Drawings";
                        fold1.Type = "FC";
                        fold1.OwnerID = Base.Project.Current.CreatedByID; //change to proj manager item.UsrProjectMan get guid
                        ent1.Activities.Update(fold1);
                        ent1.TimeActivity.Current.Summary = "Drawnings";
                        ent1.TimeActivity.Current.TrackTime = true;
                        ent1.TimeActivity.Current.IsBillable = false;
                        ent1.TimeActivity.Current.ProjectID = Base.Project.Current.ContractID;
                        ent1.TimeActivity.Current.ProjectTaskID = projTID;          
                        ent1.Actions.PressSave();
```